# How to get annotation values in java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have class Person:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MaxLength {
int length();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface NotNull {

}

public class Person {

private int age;

private String name;

public Person(int age, String name) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
}

@NotNull
public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
}

@MaxLength(length = 3)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}


}
```

Then I'm trying to print annotation values of methods of Peson object.

```
 for (Method method : o.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
            Annotation[] annotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
            for (Annotation a : annotations) {
              Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(a.getClass());
                    System.out.println(method.getName().substring(3) + " " +
                           annotation);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want it to print annotation values, but it prints `null`. I m not quite understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: When you have the `Annotation a` just use it, don't look it up again.  If you have a look at this code in your debugger it should be clearer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey it now prints "@MaxLength(length=3)", but I want just "3" and I can't find the way to do it without working with concrete annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the annotations as shown below. Have modified the code a bit:

```
Person personobject = new Person(6, "Test");
MaxLength maxLengthAnnotation;
Method[] methods = personobject.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method : methods) {
if (method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
    // check added to avoid run time exception
    if(method.isAnnotationPresent(MaxLength.class)) {
        maxLengthAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(MaxLength.class);
        System.out.println(method.getName().substring(3) + " " + maxLengthAnnotation.length());
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume I don't know what the annotations are.

Comment: If you don't know what the annotations are, how will you know which property of the annotation is required? Like, we are trying to access `lenght` property by doing `maxLengthAnnotation.length()`, so if you do not know what is the annotation, how will you determine which property to read?

Answer (score 0):

Use the annotation class name like -

```
method.getAnnotation(MaxLength.class);
method.getAnnotation(NotNull.class);
```

or you can get all annotation array using another function -

```
Annotation annotations[] = method.getAnnotations();
```

and iterate the annotations