# How to get @Attribute name?

Tags: java, spring-annotations

I have this annotated java class and would like to get the name from **@Attribute(name = "HSS-EsmApnId")** and then get the value from the following String to make a Map.

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.naming.Name;

import org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Attribute;
import org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry;
import org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Id;

@Entry(objectClasses = {"HSS-EsmApn"}, base = "nodeName=jambala")
public final class Apn {

    @Id
    private Name dn;

    @Attribute(name = "HSS-EsmApnId") // this name would be the key
    private String apnId; // and apnId would be the value

    @Attribute(name = "HSS-EsmApnName")
    private String apnName;

    @Attribute(name = "groupId")
    private String groupId;

    @Attribute(name = "objectClass")
    private List<String> objectClass;

    @Attribute(name = "ownerId")
    private String ownerId;

    @Attribute(name = "permissions")
    private String permissions;

    @Attribute(name = "shareTree")
    private String shareTree;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Apn [dn=" + dn + ", apnId=" + apnId + ", apnName=" + apnName + ", groupId=" + groupId + ", objectClass="
            + objectClass + ", ownerId=" + ownerId + ", permissions=" + permissions + ", shareTree=" + shareTree
            + "]";
    }
}
```

I've tried to use Annotation but I am only able to get the **@Entry** annotation values.

```
    Class<?> clazz = Apn.class;
    System.out.println(clazz);

    java.lang.annotation.Annotation[] annotations = clazz.getAnnotations();
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        System.out.println(annotation.annotationType());
    }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at [Get Annotation Value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28673460/1680403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for **class** level annotations. What you want to do, is get **field** level annotations:

```
Field field = Apn.class.getDeclaredField("apnId");
Annotation[] annotations = field.getAnnotations();
```

Also, if you want to get specific annotation, you can use `field.getAnnotationsByType(Entry.class)`, which would give you access to the specific class of the annotation and its parameters, such as `name`, as you need in your case.